# Solutions to non-linear equation with positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming, lyapunov-functions

Let $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ be real $m\times n$ matrices with $m>n$, $\rho$ be a scalar and $\Sigma$ be a positive definite $n\times n$ matrix. I would like to find conditions on $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ which guarantee that the solutions $(\rho_1,\Sigma_1)$ of the following equation all have $\rho_1=\rho$. The equation is

$$\mathbf{A}\Sigma_1\mathbf{A}^\top+\rho_1\mathbf{B}\Sigma_1\mathbf{B}^\top=\mathbf{A}\Sigma\mathbf{A}^\top+\rho\mathbf{B}\Sigma\mathbf{B}^\top$$

There are no restrictions on $\rho_1$, but $\Sigma_1$ must be positive definite. Clearly, $\Sigma_1=\Sigma,\rho_1=\rho$ is a solution, but I would like to make assumptions such that all solutions have $\rho_1=\rho$.

Comment: I should add that at the very least we require $\mathbf{A}\neq\mathbf{B}$!

Comment: In fact, we require $\mathbf{A}\neq\delta\mathbf{B}$ for some scalar $\delta$.

Comment: It may be helpful to note that this equation can be rewritten as
$$
\mathbf A (\Sigma_1 - \Sigma) \mathbf A^T = \mathbf B(\rho \Sigma - \rho_1 \Sigma_1)\mathbf B^T.
$$

Answer (score 1):

One gets infinitely many solutions if $A$ and $B$ are of the form

\begin{align}
A &= C\,X\,\Omega, \\
B &= \gamma\,C\,Y\,\Omega,
\end{align}

with

- $C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$,
- $\Omega$ such that $\Omega\,\Sigma\,\Omega^\top = I$,
- $X,Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ orthogonal matrices, i.e. $X\,X^\top = Y\,Y^\top = I$,
- $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$.

The solutions in this case are

$$
\Sigma_1 = \frac{1 + \gamma\,\rho}{1 + \gamma\,\rho_1}\,\Sigma,\ \forall\,\rho_1 \in \left\{x\in\mathbb{R} \left|\frac{1 + \gamma\,\rho}{1 + \gamma\,x} > 0\right.\right\}.
$$

---

By using [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) and the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) the equation can also be written as

$$
\left(A \otimes A + \rho_1\,B \otimes B\right) \text{vec}(\Sigma_1) = \text{vec}(A\,\Sigma\,A^\top + \rho\,B\,\Sigma\,B^\top),
$$

which only has a solution if $\text{vec}(A\,\Sigma\,A^\top + \rho\,B\,\Sigma\,B^\top)$ lies in the column space of $A \otimes A + \rho_1\,B \otimes B$. Because of the linear contribution, due to $\rho_1$, of $B \otimes B$ to the column space, I believe there either can be only one solution ($\rho_1=\rho$) or infinitely many. However, I am not entirely sure if the cases from the previous section are the only ways to get infinitely many solutions.